# Формы и Сpp

Tags: winforms, c++

Собственно вопрос.
Почему с языками вроде C#, VBasic в MSVS при создании `Win`-проекта сразу появляется `FormBuilder` и можно перетаскиванием мыши быстро накидать форму и описать нужные обработчики событий, а плюсы такой возможностью обделили? Ну т.е. есть `wxWidgets`, к примеру, `MFC`, `Qt`, но писать ручками графический интерфейс, как-то, хм, не наглядно что-ли. Было бы разумно автоматизировать этот процесс до работы мышью, я думаю.
Почему так сложилось и каковы были тому исторические предпосылки? Есть ли какая-то библиотека\IDE (с поддержкой современных компиляторов), которая как-то исправляет сложившуюся ситуацию?
Просто, ну реально, как-то неохотно мне писать иерархию классов с наследованием на `wxWidgets` когда мне нужно создать приложение с тремя кнопками и парой `Edit'ов` для подсчета накладных, к примеру.

Comment: Наксколько я знаю, то C++ не для того создавался, чтобы нарисовать форму, потом накидать на неё контролов, а то, что получилось компилировать. Для этого есть Delphi.
Ну а создание формы в wxWidgets, занимает не так уж и много времени.

Answer (score 1):

MFC одна из первых библиотек для GUI, первая версия ЕМНИП вышла в 93 году, параллельно с ней появились как 2 капли воды похожая wxWidges. Обе не имели графических редакторов, и обе скорее напоминают обертку макросами над API (хотя и ооп и MVC там есть, в каком виде - плавающие знают хД). Исторически ли сложилась так или это злой умысел разработчиков, нужно смотреть автобиографию ;).

По сабжу - для wxWidgets есть несколько живых и неочень редакторов, в т.ч. плагин для code::blocks. В MFC кроме встроенного редактора диалогов не видел.

ЗЫ. Библиотек ближе к API врятли можно встретить, отчего производительность у них на высоте.  Есть мнение что для них редакторы будут вредны.

Answer (score 0):

Почему обделили? Ни разу не обделили.

1. Есть C++ Builder. По сути - те же Дельфи, но в качестве языка программирования используется С++
2. В MSVS тоже можно "визуально" программировать. Но там действительно редактор форм появляется не сразу, а его нужно самому вызывать. Потом там спокойно пишется код. Т.е. просто подсовываете свои обработчики стандартных событий. В MFC наследовать от базовых классов контролов имеет смысл лишь тогда, когда расширяете их функционал. Ну, или переопределяете поведение контрола.

Comment: C++ builder, это который 96 года?

Comment: "Визуально" в MSVS перетаскиваются только кнопки в ресурсные диалоги, да создаются обработчики событий для них. Остальное ручками.

Comment: @pol500 "C++ Builder 96 года"
не только, есть и новые версии, например C++ Builder XE2(в начале этого года появился, вроде бы), Builder'ы также, как и Delphi активно поддерживаются Embarcadero

Comment: @pol500, имеется в виду C++ Builder как продукт Embarcadero, поавопреемника Borland/Inprise.
@Dith Касательно кнопочек в MSVC - думаю, неверно. Никаких заморок с элементами вроде чекбоксов, радиокнопок, меню, текстбоксов и комбобоксов не заметил. Скажите, что Вы не можете с полтычка реализовать, без дописывания ф-ла ручками.

Answer (score 0):

> Почему так сложилось и каковы были тому исторические предпосылки?

Причины просты. Раньше компьютеры были не такие мощьные. Страшно подумать, когда то не то что мыши, а и других привычных вещей не было. Когда то интерфейс вообще был только текстовый и графический редактор не нужен был. С# создавался те времена, когда о том, что когда то windows  не существовало, многие уже и не помнили.

> а плюсы такой возможностью обделили?
> нужно понимать, что "плюсы" - это язык более широкий, чем просто создание gui. Если для программ на с++ нужен gui, то просто берут подходящую библиотеку. А в ней может быть удобный (а это очень субъективно) редактор.

К тому же, подумайте, как стандартизовать графический интерфейс под разные платформы, на плюсах ведь не только под Windows пишут.

Поэтому, С++ никто не ущемлял. Как раз наоборот.

Comment: @KoVadim, только не C#, а C++. C#, как известно, появился уже после создания .net-платформы...

> как стандартизовать графический интерфейс под разные платформы

Написать свою кросс-платформенную библиотеку. Как, например, Qt. Кстати, успешная (относительно) попытка борланда сделать что-то подобное называется Kylix. Но это вроде как Дельфи, но под линукс :-)

Comment: вчитайтесь внимательно в мою фразу. Там имелось ввиду, что с# появился тогда, когда windows была привычным делом.

Comment: ОК, соглашусь, читал по диагонали, но все равно фраза кривовата =)

Answer (score 0):

Для Qt есть очень удобное средство визуального создания интерфейсов: Qt Creator и Qt Disigner. Даже для GTK есть программа, называемая Glade. Так что, ничем С++ не обделен. Даже наоборот.

Да и ручками в Qt писать интерфейс не так уж и сложно.